# Deletion in LinkedHashMap vs HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, time-complexity

Is it correct that deletion in `LinkedHashMap` takes linear time. Since we need to delete the key from the linked list that maintains the order of insertion and it would take `O(n)` time. In regular `HashMap` deletion takes constant time.

Comment: Reference to particular linked-list node is stored internally with entry, so deletion is also O(1)

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yeah, this makes sense. If you post your answer I'll accept it, because you specified exactly why it is constant.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe it is not an answer, just a comment =)

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), it is not:

> This class provides all of the optional `Map` operations, and permits null elements. Like `HashMap`, it provides *constant-time performance for the basic operations (`add`, `contains` and `remove`)*, assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets. Performance is likely to be just slightly below that of HashMap, due to the added expense of maintaining the linked list, with one exception: Iteration over the collection-views of a `LinkedHashMap` requires time proportional to the *size* of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a `HashMap` is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its *capacity*.

`LinkedHashMap` does not override the `HashMap#remove(Object key)` method. The latter removes the entry corresponding to the key from the table and calls a `recordRemoval()` method on the deleted entry, which adjusts the links of the previous and next to the removed one. There is no iteration on the list in order to delete node at a certain index.

Answer (score 4):

LinkedHasMap uses an Entry that subclasses HashMap.Entry, so the cost is higher but still constant.

Every time a entry is deleted in HashMap the method recordRemoval(HashMap m) is called. Its implementation in HashMap.Entry is empty but LinkedHasMap. Entry just delete the entry from the list):

```
/**
 * Removes this entry from the linked list.
 */
private void remove() {
    before.after = after;
    after.before = before;
```

}

The sequence is as follows:

- remove implementation in HashMap calls removeEntryForKey (HashMap:line551)

  ```
  public V remove(Object key) {
      Entry<K,V> e = removeEntryForKey(key);
      return (e == null ? null : e.value);
  }
  ```
- removeEntryForKey in HashMap calls entry.recordRemoval(this) (HashMap:line560)

  ```
  final Entry<K,V> removeEntryForKey(Object key) {
      [...]
      while (e != null) {
          Entry<K,V> next = e.next;
          Object k;
          if (e.hash == hash &&
              ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k)))) {
              [...]
              e.recordRemoval(this);
              return e;
          }
          prev = e;
          e = next;
      }
      return e;
  }
  ```
- recordRemoval implementation in LinkedHasMap.Entry calls remove method above, which is O(1) (LinkedHashMap:line357)

  ```
  void recordRemoval(HashMap<K,V> m) {
      remove();
  }
  ```

Source for HashMap:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Source for LinkedHashMap:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java